# C++ map comparator

Tags: c++, dictionary

For a c++ map declared like:

```
map < set<int>,int > x;
```

What is the default comparator function that the compiler uses?
My code using this statement executed successfully but I am not sure about the comparator it uses.

Comment: As you can see from [any documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), the comparator defaults to `std::less<K>` for `std::map<K, T>`. This in turn forwards `<` to its arguments, and `operator<` is overloaded for [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp).

Answer (score 3):

For a `std::map<K, T>`, the default comparator is `std::less<K>`.

`std::less<K>` uses `lhs < rhs` as the default way to compare.

In your case, you end up using:

```
bool operator<(std::set<int> const& lhs, std::set<int> const& rhs)
```

Answer (score 2):

For default this should resolve to

```
bool operator<(const std::set<int>&, const std::set<int>&)
```

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/operator_cmp) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For both `std::map` and `std::set` there is a optional template parameter that defines the comparison type (and another one for the allocator.) using this you can use any comparison, including a user defined function!

In both these cases, it defaults to `std::less`

Look at the docs for each!!

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/